# How do I print the contents of an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have created and initialized an array with the following strings:

```
char print_names[][10] = {"\t\t1. John\n",
                          "\t\t2. Smith\n",
                          "\t\t3. Jane\n",
                          "\t\t4. Mary\n",
                          "\t\t5. Lisa\n"};
```

As far as I know, the name of the array is a pointer itself. so when I put these lines:

```
    printf("%c", *print_names[0]);
    printf("%c", *print_names[1]);
```

It should point to the content of the that array element. But nothing is printed out on the console.

I went into the debugger and it clearly shows that each element holds the appropriate string. I'm not sure where I did wrong.

EDIT: I'm still learning the basic about array and pointer, so I didn't include `<string.h>` in the file.

Additional question: is it possible to print the content (the names) without using string?

OK. I figured it out. I think I understand now. Thanks for answering.

Comment: 1) What is the *type* of `*print_combos[0]` (and how does it differ from `print_combos[0]`)? 2) What is the *purpose* of "%c" (and how does it differ from "%s" and what type does each expect)?

Comment: Format specified for string is `%s`, not `%c`.

Comment: Sorry I went back and change the print_combos to print_names. It was a typo.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what the variable is called - the types / scopes / usages are still the same after edits.

Comment: Then in that case the type of `*print_names[0]` should be `char*`, or a character type pointer right?

Comment: Be careful with the strings, one of the strings in the array (as you show it) will *not* be null-terminated, and thus treating it as a null-terminated string (like printing it with the `%s` format) will lead to *undefined behavior*. Better increase the size of the array from `10` to something larger.

Comment: `*print_names[0]` and `*print_names[1]` happen to be the first two characters of the two first strings you have in your array, which are tabs, so it's normall you don't see anything, can you see the tabs? a blank space?  can you see the transparency of air?

Answer (score 2):

`*print_names[0]` is equal to `print_names[0][0]`. It's the first character of the first string in `print_names`.

And as the first character of every string in the `print_names` array is a tab (`'\t'`) you print this tab which isn't really visible.

If you want to print the string itself you need to use `%s` as the format, and pass a pointer to the first character. Which can be done as:

```
printf("%s", print_names[0]);
```

---

On the other hand, if you *want* to print the tab, and make it seen, then surround the output with other characters. Like

```
printf("tab = \"%c\"\n", print_names[0][0]);
```

which will print the tab surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Leading tabs will be "visible" as they will be rendered (displayed? emitted?) as 4/8 spaces eg. on the console or text editor.

Comment: @user2864740 But how do you see a space, unless you print something after it?

Comment: All of the strings have leading tabs, not trailing tabs.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, and the OP is printing *only* the first tab, nothing else.

Comment: True. Such comes down to the fundamental problem: "It should point to the [entire] content of the that array element."

Comment: @user2864740 Which is addressed by my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The array `print_names` has 2 dimensions:

- the number of elements is determined from the initializer: 5 in your example
- the number of `char` elements in each element in the array is defined to `10`.

The problem is 5 of the initializers have exactly 10 characters and one has 11 characters. The initializer is inconsistent with the object definition and none of the elements are null terminated strings.

You should change the width to at least 12 and you can use `printf()` to print the array elements this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array() {
    char print_names[][12] = {
        "\t\t1. John\n",
        "\t\t2. Smith\n",
        "\t\t3. Jane\n",
        "\t\t4. Mary\n",
        "\t\t5. Lisa\n"
    };
    size_t count = sizeof(print_names) / sizeof(print_names[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s", print_names[i]);
    }
}
```

Regarding your approach:

> *As far as I know, the name of the array is a pointer itself.*

Not really: the name of the array just that. When you use the name of an array in an expression other than `sizeof(n)`, it *decays* into a pointer to the first element of the array.

The lines below output the first byte of the first and second strings:

```
printf("%c", *print_names[0]);  // same as print_names[0][0]
printf("%c", *print_names[1]);  // same as print_names[1][0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the escape sequences!

Could you elaborate why you used the size_t and sizeof?

Are you targeting the memory allocated directly (i.e. more precise) rather than just using the constant 5?

Comment: @karln-create: you can compute the number of elements of an array `a` by dividing its size in byte `sizeof(a)` by the size of an element `sizeof(a[0])`. This works for any array but `a` must be an actual array, not a pointer nor a function argument.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I forgot that I can just literally put a math operation in when declaring array size. I'm a beginner so it takes a little bit for me understand all the little parts.

Answer (score 0):

As you have overdimensioned the array (with 10 entries, but you have only filled 5, the others are filled with `NULL` pointers) you can print the array contents (one string per line) with:

```
char **p;
for (p = print_names; *p; p++)
    printf("%s", *p);
```

which is equivalent to this code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; print_names[i]; i++)
    printf("%s", print_names[i]);
```

of if you know that there are 5 elements in the array:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%s", print_names[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works ,but because the first element of each row is \t you won't see any thing you can also use

`printf("%s", print_names[0])`

to print : \t\t1. John\n
this row.

notice you're placing more than 10 characters in second dimension of your array.